# How to resolve error regarding on MySQL in ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody help me to solve the following error ?When i typed rake db:create on cmd i got these errors.

Error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x1a1af20>

Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When i run rake db:create --trace i got the following traces.

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #

Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

```
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x1a37888>
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_adapters/connection_specification.rb:150:in `resolve_all'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connect
ion_handling.rb:69:in `resolve'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb
:46:in `configurations='
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/railtie
s/databases.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block i
n execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute
'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block i
n invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_
with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block i
n invoke_prerequisites'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_
prerequisites'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block i
n invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_
with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `
invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `
block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `
run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `
top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `b
lock in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `r
un'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
```

My database.yml file is described below.

```
default:&default
  adapter:mysql2
  encoding:utf8
  pool:5
  username:root
  password:pass
  host:localhost

development:<<:*default
  database:sqlbook_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:<<:*default
  database:sqlbook_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:<<:*default
  database:sqlbook_production
  username:sqlbook
  password:pass
```

I am using rails version 4.2.0 and ruby 1.9.3.Please help me to resolve this error.Thanks in advance..

Comment: In your code somewhere you are iterating using .each on string instead of array

Comment: Hello Triveni,I have not created any code right now.First i created new project by typing the command "rails new sqlbook -d mysql".When project has created i went to that directory and typed the command "rake db:create" after that i got the above error.I can not guess where that .each will present.If you have any idea please share with me and please try to solve this error.

Comment: Are you able to run rake db:create command?

Comment: If you get same error. Please try to use ruby 2 instead of ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Try to upgrade your ruby version. Or go through online which possible set of rails and ruby version do match.?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920731/how-to-solve-nomethod-error-in-ror-4